# Return from a for loop in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have a game with a computer AI that saves info to an array and I need to loop through the array, which is fine but once it finds the value I'm looking for it keeps searching, normaly this would not be a problem but the arrays can get quite large and I'd prefer to be able to simply stop the loop once I have the values that I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `break` statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    if (i == 2) {
        // Exit the loop on the 3rd iteration
        break;
    }
}
```

This also works in `(for ... in ...)` loops.